How to differentiate between two button clicks with confirm dialogue (SweetAlert) in PHP?
I use SweetAlert 2 for dialogues and I also use it to let the user confirm a button click. In one form I have two buttons, but because of the confirm dialogue the name of the button is not sent, so that I cannot check whether 'btnName' is set in $_POST.
Here How to execute a PHP script upon SweetAlert2 confirmation? a similar questions was asked and the solution provided works well with one button.
But with two buttons the problem is that the hidden value is always transmitted and cannot serve to check which of the buttons was pressed. Is there a way to achieve that?
Thank you!
I tried to place two hidden fields directly above the respective button, but still both values are transmitted no matter which of the buttons is clicked. So this does not help.
I use this code:
PHP:
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
// delete one entry
}
if(isset($_POST['deleteAll'])) {
// delete all entries
}

HTML:
<form id="mainForm" action="php.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="">
<button type="button" onclick="confirm('mainForm')">Delete</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="deleteAll" value="">
<button type="button" onclick="confirm('mainForm')">DeleteAll</button>
</form>

<script>
function confirm(formID) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: '',
        text: "Are you sure?",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'No',
        reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            document.getElementById(formID).submit();
        }
    })
}
</script>


try this:
<form id="mainForm" action="php.php" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="delete" onclick="return confirmSubmit();">
   <input type="submit" name="deleteAll" onclick="return confirmSubmit();">
</form>

<script>
function confirmSubmit() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: '',
        text: "Are you sure?",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'No',
        reverseButtons: true
    }).then((result) => {
        return result.isConfirmed
    })
}
</script>

